# Using href attribute for button element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need that use `href=""` attribute for button

like this `<button href="link">click me</button>` Instead of `<a href="link">`

that's wrong .

I think that I've to try this code

```
<button onClick="FN('MY Link For Example www.stackoverflow.com')" >click me</button>

<script>
function FN('URL'){
     --> Go to MY Link For Example www.stackoverflow.com
}
<script>
```

So what do u guys suggest I should do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. This will navigate to the link on click.

```
 <button onclick="window.location.href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why you don't use `<a type="button" href=""></a>`

Or if you really want a button, so  `<button onclick="window.location.href=""></button>`

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve your problem

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">
    <button>click me</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

href attribute can not be used on button tag , if you want button like appearance for your a tag you can use add style to your a tag and make it look like button , add bootstrap reference then add button class to your anchor tag.
[Custom Bootstrap Button](http://bootsnipp.com/buttons)  , but if you still want to use button tag then adding *onclick* event is better option